# Can I create an online version of a game?

Tags: game-development, legal

Can I create an online version of a card game? Just for experimenting. Is there any possible legal implication?
In this case the card game is called [Rick and Morty: Total Rickall](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/194232/rick-and-morty-total-rickall-card-game).

Comment: This question might be better off at our sister site [law.se]. There aren't many legal experts here ...

Comment: This question rose at our big brother site BGG.  https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/399061/i-want-program-board-game-need-legal-info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. Maybe.

What you definitely can't do is to use the name "Rick and Morty", any art from the game or anything else which is covered by copyright, trade marks or any other form of intellectual property which is owned by anyone other than you.

However, it is probable that [game mechanics themselves cannot be copyrighted](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/273935/Texas_court_affirms_game_mechanics_not_protected_under_copyright_law.php), so you may be able to create a game which has exactly the same mechanics as *Rick and Morty: Total Rickall*, but with your own art, your own name, etc. However, if this becomes at all popular, I'd still expect the publishers of the game and/or the Rick and Morty rights holders to make your life difficult. You *might* win in court, but it's probably not worth the fight.

Comment: Certainly *some* games have had sanctioned-but-unofficial implementations made, so you can try contacting the publisher, but with the R&M brand it's likely they don't even have the rights to let you have the rights to do that.

Comment: The Chips n Guac game seems to be a good example of this.

Comment: Programs like Cockatrice work around it by presenting themselves as very generic "tabletop simulators" that just so happen to enable all mechanics required to play - in this case - Magic: The Gathering. They also don't include any card images - those could in theory be found elsewhere on the Internet.